# handleClick function not working on parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, parent-child

I have a react parent component, that renders a list of QuestionCard components, using the map function. I'm trying to place an onClick function inside each QuestionCard component (I want this function to be inside the parent component, and not the QuestionCard component code), but it's not working (I'm not getting a console log of 'working'). How could I solve this, and why is this happening in the first place?

Here is the code for the parent component:

```
class QuestionList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            counter: 0,
            scorekeeper: 0
        }

        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick() {
        console.log('working')
    }

    render() {
        var createQuestionsList = this.props.questions.map((question, i) => {
            return <QuestionCard 
                    onClick={this.handleClick}
                    key={i} 
                    question={question.question}
                    choice1={question.choice1}
                    choice2={question.choice2}
                    choice3={question.choice3}
                    choice4={question.choice4}
                    answer={question.answer}
                   />
        });
        return (
            <div>
                {createQuestionsList}
                <button>submit answers</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        questions: state.questions
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(QuestionList);
```

and here is the code for the child component:

```
export default class QuestionCard extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            hideDiv: false
        }

        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick(choice) {
        this.setState(prevState => ({hideDiv: !prevState.hideDiv});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{margin: '20px', display: this.state.hideDiv ? 'none' : 'block'}}>
                <div>
                    {this.props.question}
                </div>

                <div style={{
                        margin: '20px', 
                        width: '500px', 
                        display: 'flex', 
                        justifyContent: 'space-around',
                        display: this.state.hideDiv ? 'none' : 'block'
                      }}>
                    <div onClick={() => this.handleClick(this.props.choice1)}>
                        {this.props.choice1}
                    </div>
                    <div onClick={() => this.handleClick(this.props.choice2)}>
                        {this.props.choice2}
                    </div>
                    <div onClick={() => this.handleClick(this.props.choice3)}>
                        {this.props.choice3}
                    </div>
                    <div onClick={() => this.handleClick(this.props.choice4)}>
                        {this.props.choice4}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your QuestionCard component, you never call the click handler you passed as props.

You need to call the `this.props.handleClick` to trigger the parent's onClick handler.

```
 handleClick(choice) {
     this.setState(prevState => ({hideDiv: !prevState.hideDiv});
     this.props.handleClick();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In QuestionCard, you're not calling the `handleClick` function that you are passing in as props from the parent.
`this.props.handleClick` will call your parent method

```
handleClick(choice) {
  this.setState(prevState => ({hideDiv: !prevState.hideDiv});
  this.props.handleClick();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `QuestionList` you passed `onClick` prop to `QuestionCard`. In order to get it to work use `this.props.onClick` in `QuestionCard` component. Then `handleClick` in `QuestionList` component will be called.

```
handleClick(choice) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({hideDiv: !prevState.hideDiv});
    this.props.onClick();
}
```